# Java how to prevent null object exception

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to write less and less code and I am trying to find a way to prevent crashes.

An example what I have encountered is:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private User user;

   public MyClass()
   {
       // Get user from another class
       // Another thread, user can be null for couple of seconds or minutes
       // Asynchronous call
       user = AnotherClass.getUser();

       // start method
       go();
   }

   private void go()
   {
      // Method 1
      // Program it is crashing if user is null
      if (user.getId() == 155)
      {
         // TO DO
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("User is NOT 155 !");
      }

      // Method 2
      // Program still crashes if user is null
      if (user != null && user.getId() == 155)
      {
         // To do
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("user is not 155");
      }

      // Method 3
      // Program wont crash, but I write much more code !
      if (user != null)
      {
         if (user.getId() == 155)
         {
            // To do
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("User is not 155 !");
         }
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("User is not 155 !");
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, method 3 it's working, but I am writing much more code... What should I do?

Comment: method 2 should work too. recheck it. in java if first part is false second part not evaluated.

Comment: The point is not that it doesn't work, but that it's relatively verbose

Answer (score 2):

Prefer the way  [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), That is method 2.

> when the first argument of the **AND** function evaluates to **false**, the overall value must be **false**;

```
      if (user != null && user.getId() == 155)
      {
         // To do
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("user is not 155");
      }
```

That is the most preferable and readable code.

Your assumtions are wrong that method2 crash and method3 works.  In the above code if  `user != null`  then only `user.getId() == 155`  executes.

Comment: What if I swap the two conditions? if (user.getId() == 155 && user != null) ?

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian You end up with Null pointer exception. If you swap those conditions then its like `if (user.getId() == 155)
      {if(user != null){}`, which does'nt make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) here, so instead of setting user to be null, set it to a special 'null' case (implementation) of the `User` object ?

e.g.

```
user = AnotherClass.getUser();
if (user == null) {
   user = new NullUser();
}
```

(ideally AnotherClass.getUser() would do the null check internally)

In this case

```
user.getId()
```

could return a special value (-1 ?) which would never equate to a valid user id. Hence your code will always look like:

```
if (user.getId() == 155)
```

The same would apply to other methods on the `User` object.

Comment: What if I edit the User class and add a field id with a default value of -1 ?

private int id = -1; public User(/* params */){}

Comment: Perhaps that would be suitable too

Answer (score 1):

It's got to be something inside the block started by this statement:

`if (user != null && user.getId() == 155)`

That is logically identical to method 3. When the JVM sees that `user` is null, it should stop evaluating that.

I will say though that I encountered something like this with JVM 1.3, so if you are using a really old JVM that may be it.